# Distributing the contents of a cell across a range

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

How would I go about distributing the contents of a cell in excel across a specified range based on a defined factor?

E.g. Cell A1 contains `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`
The desired result is to spread that series over the range A1:A9

Or a more complex example: A1 contains `apple, orange; 34; 67, "pod"`
The desired result is to spread the contents separated by the differing punctuation over the range B1:F1

Thanks.

Comment: Does this need to be done in vba? If not, excel has a handy "Text to Columns" built in tool that will do exactly this (under the Data tab)

Answer (score 2):

Use Data -> Text to Columns to do this:

http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/text-to-columns.html

Answer (score 1):

In VBA

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SpreadListsInColA()

    Dim c As Range, itms As Variant

    With Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns("A")
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For Each c In .Cells
            If Not IsError(c) Then
                If Len(c.Value2) > 0 And InStr(c.Value2, ",") > 0 Then

                    itms = Split(c.Value2, ",")

                    c.Offset(, 1).Resize(, UBound(itms) + 1) = itms

                End If
            End If
        Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This UDF will *almost* deal with the first scenario.  As it's a function then the original text will remain in cell A1 and this will distribute over the cells you've entered the formula in.

In `A2:A10` or `A2:I2` enter this array formula: **=Transpose_Ext(A1,",")**

```
Public Function Transpose_Ext(Source As Range, Delim As String) As Variant

    With Application.Caller
        If Source.Cells.Count = 1 Then
            If .Rows.Count = 1 Then
                Transpose_Ext = Array(Split(Source, Delim))
            ElseIf .Rows.Count > 1 And .Columns.Count = 1 Then
                Transpose_Ext = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Array(Split(Source, Delim)))
            End If
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

To use multiple delimiters I'd add a `paramarray` as the last argument in the function to store an array of delimiters and then something to split the source value by each delimiter.

Edit:  But, as already mentioned, text to columns and the Transpose function will do the job just as well.